# Program printing unusual numbers when vector has 6 elements (C++, vectors, loops)

Tags: c++, for-loop, vector, output

I am getting into coding and have been studying some C++ over at Codecademy.
I have written the following code as part of an exercise in using vectors, where I had to write a program that finds the sum of even numbers and the product of odd numbers in a vector

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {

  //Declaring variables
  int i, sum = 0;
  int product = 1;
  std::vector<int> example = {2,4,3,6,1,8};

  //Loop for calculations
  for (i = 0; i <= example.size(); i++)
    {

        if (example[i] % 2 == 0)
        {

            sum = sum + example[i];

        }

        else

        {

            product = product * example[i];

        }

    }

  std::cout << "Sum of even numbers: " << sum << "\n";
  std::cout << "Product of odd numbers: "<< product << "\n";

}
```

The thing about this little piece of code, is that the output for the product of the odd numbers is 396147.

Removing the 6th element yields the correct result, as the output I see is 3 (which is the output I should have gotten regardless, since I haven't changed the number of odd numbers in my vector).

Similarly, ADDING elements also gets the program to print the correct numbers, making me think that there is something wrong specifically with calculating the product of the odd numbers in my vector whenever I have exactly 6 elements.

Please note that calculating the sum of the even numbers in the vector remains apt no matter the number of elements.

Examples of outputs for different vectors:

Vectors with 6 elements:
std::vector example = {2,4,3,6,1,9}; -> the output for the product of the odd numbers is 3565323.

std::vector example = {2,4,3,6,1,5}; -> the output for the product of the odd numbers is 1980735.

Vector with 5 elements:
std::vector example = {2,4,3,6,1}; -> the output for the product of the odd numbers is 3.

Vector with 7 elements:
std::vector example = {2,4,3,6,1,4,8}; -> the output for the product of the odd numbers is 1980735.

Any idea why this is happening?
Thanks.

Comment: `for (i = 0; i <= example.size(); i++)` should be `for (i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)`

Comment: as we are in the year 2019, you should simplify with `for( auto n: example ) ... `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an out of bounds access in your loop:

```
for (i = 0; i <= example.size(); i++)
//            ^^ this is the bug
```

as this is how indexing works:

```
std::vector<int> example = {2, 4, 3, 6, 1, 8};
// indices:                 0  1  2  3  4  5
```

where it becomes obvious that `example.size()`, which is `6` in this example, is outside of the container. The loop should be changed to

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
```

as if `i = example.size()`, `example[i]` yields undefined behavior. Note further that I have reduced the scope of your loop counter `i`, which can be declared in the init-part of the for loop, and changed its type to `std::size_t`, which is the actual type used for indexing containers of the standard library.

Comment: Following this logic, why are my vectors (of any size) working at all? Shouldn't a 5 element vector have problems with the 5th element and so on?

Comment: The nature of undefined behavior is that anything can happen. You can't make any assumptions on what the result is.

Answer (score 2):

it should be `for (i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)` since array/vector indexing starts at `0` and the last entry has index `size()-1`.

Answer (score -4):

problem in your loop with vector so any array or vector is assign from 0th index and move to (n-1) last index

## include

```
#include <vector>

int main() {

  //Declaring variables
  int i, sum = 0;
  int product = 1;
  std::vector<int> example = {2,4,3,6,1,8};

  //Loop for calculations
  for (i = 0; i < example.size(); i++)
    {

        if (example[i] % 2 == 0)
        {

            sum = sum + example[i];

        }

        else

        {

            product = product * example[i];

        }

    }

  std::cout << "Sum of even numbers: " << sum << "\n";
  std::cout << "Product of odd numbers: "<< product << "\n";

}
```

Comment: No explanation, only a repost with a single char modified and also as an answer already given...

Comment: What have you changed and why? Please add such explanation to your answer such that others can learn from it